# Approximating continuous functions on a product space

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, continuity

I have read in a paper that all bounded continuous functions

$$f:[0,t] \times S \to \Bbb R$$ can be uniformly approximated by functions of   the form

$$f(s,w) = \sum_{m=1}^{N}a_mg_m(s)f_m(w)$$

(for some $N \geq 1$, scalars $a_i$ and bounded continuous real-valued functions $g_i,f_i$ on $[0,t],S$ respectively with $S$ compact) How? Hint: Use Stone-Weistrass theorem

Comment: Can you please rewrite this a little more clearly? It seems to consist of a declarative sentence (whose last bits, "$S, S$ compact" are baffling) and a sentence fragment. What is the actual *question*?

Comment: @JohnHughes: Sorry, changed now.

Comment: Whose hint is that? Your hint to us?

Comment: @user21820: It is written in the paper itself.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you know what the Stone-Weierstraß theorem says?

If so, you simply have to take the algebra $A$ as $$A := \bigg\{f \,\bigg|\, f(s,w) = \sum_m a_m g_m(s) f_m(w) \forall (s,w) \text{ for suitable continuous functions } g_m, f_m\bigg\}.$$

Verify that this is indeed an algebra!

Then you have to verify that $A$ contains the constants (easy) and seperates the points of $[0,t] \times S$.

Here, you will have to assume that $S$ is Hausdorff (or something like that) and invoke (e.g.) Urysohn's Lemma.

Comment: does this solution also apply to this question?: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1786936/weirstrass-approximation-theorem-for-a-product-space

Comment: @JessyCat: Yes, it does.